# Banach dual space integral

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $f_t \in X^*$ for each $t \in [0,t_0]$. Suppose that
$$\int_0^{t_0} f_t(x) = 0$$
for all $x \in X$.

1) Does it make sense to write $\int_0^{t_0}f_t = 0$?

2) If so, does this follow from the above property?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the Bochner or Pettis integral?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, sort of. I wonder if the expression I write above in 1) makes sense though.